# How to append text to the end of the first line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open ("a.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write("Hello ")
```

Currently, this enters into the text file as shown below.

```
hello
hello
```

I've also tried

```
for line in f:
    f.write(line.replace("\n", ""))
```

which didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did it not work?

Comment: Are you trying to insert text into a line in an existing file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use:

```
with open ("a.txt", "r") as f, open ("b.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.write(f.read().rstrip()+"hello ")
    os.rename("b.txt", "a.txt")
```

Comment: @U9-Forward f.read() is coming up empty for some reason, any ideas?

Comment: @Dansey You should only use my code, make my code the full code for it to work.

Comment: @U9-Forward I've been troubleshooting this for quite a while, f.seek(0) still seems to return a blank read.

Comment: @Dansey You should just copy and paste my code into an empty file, then it should work...

Comment: @U9-Forward, yes, I'm not using the previous code, read is empty.

Comment: When you open the same file for writing, it gets truncated.

Comment: Don't open the same file twice.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Edited my answer

Comment: That's better, but it doesn't do it for the first line only and it doesn't replace the file when it's done.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I realized you don't need to `remove`.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as istr, open('output.txt', 'w') as ostr:
    for i, line in enumerate(istr):
        # Get rid of the trailing newline (if any).
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if i == 0:
            line += 'Hello'
        print(line, file=ostr)
```

Comment: You need to format your code, or better use `with open(...) as f, open(...) as f2:` it's more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an edited version of @U9-Forward's code that worked for me.

```
with open ("a.txt", "r") as f, open ("b.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.write(f.read().rstrip()+"hello ")
    os.remove("a.txt")
    os.rename("b.txt", "a.txt")
```

Comment: Any idea why this was required?

Comment: It's needed because you can't open a file twice. so you should do `remove` and `rename`.

Comment: Got it, I figured that you couldn't open it twice so I had tried to change `w` and `a+` to `r+` which just resulted in two lines.

Comment: Yup, maybe you should accept your own answer in two days, but still, you won't get +15 since it is self-accepted.